# How to create an Excel Spreadsheet that formats a field in one of a few different ways based on the data in the field

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a SQL View that I'm working on that spits out some important information for my boss's boss's boss. The view includes a field called Item ID, which can be in several different formats.

Here are some examples (that may or many not be made up to protect the innocent):
ATS-LC-PLN-RT-RH-0.3125-18-3X2.125X1.5-1
012345.012345
01234567.0123
123456789012
000000.000000
000000.000002

I'd like to take the view and use it to (eventually) produce an excel spreadsheet, but I'm not confident that there's a way to format this column in a way that will work for all of these different Item ID's.
When playing around with Excel, these numbers drop their trailing zeroes and  switch to scientific notation, among other shenanigans. I just need to format this column in a way that will preserve the Item ID.

If you know of a way to programmatically create an excel spreadsheet in a way that allows me to assign a format based on the data in the cell, that would work great. The problem that I'm mainly suffering from is that this spreadsheet naturally has hundreds of lines, soon to be thousands, and there's no feasible way to hand-format these lines one at a time on a daily or weekly basis.

I've got SQL-Server 2014 and Excel via Microsoft Office Standard 2013, which may offer more options.

Comment: In your testing have you been copying and pasting these results into excel? I would export from SQL to csv.

Comment: That doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: Yeah the only solution I know if is to manually format the cells as text. This is an excel issue.

Comment: tow option to solve it. 1.Either you import the view it self to you excel sheet. 
2.or after you paste your data use any text function for the pasted cells such as TRIM.

Comment: Do you not have an option to create the report in SSRS and have it emailed in Excel from there?

Comment: Loading data into Excel is easy, just go to the Data >Get External Data menu and select "From SQL Server". Formatting is *also* easy. Right click on the column header and click "Format Cells". Have you tried this?

Comment: Another option is to use PowerQuery instead of a plain old data connection and select, filter, format the data in there. PowerQuery allows even people that don't know SQL to filter data, select specific columns etc. The final formatting is still done by "Format Cells" for an entiry column

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is what I have been doing. I cannot right click and format a cell hundreds of times a day every day, I want to solve this programmatically or create a format that works for all of these options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permit me to suggest another way of framing your issue.  I don't think you really want to analyze (either manually or programmatically) each item ID and determine whether it is an integer, a decimal, or alphanumeric text.  Since your item ID data varies, the only Excel formatting that will work for *all* of your cases is 'Text.'  So my suggestion is look for a way to automate the export of your data to Excel while making sure that the formatting in Excel is set to 'Text' for all cells to contain your item ID data.  As you've noticed, if you are pasting data in Excel, if the target cells are not *first* set to 'Text' formatting, Excel will make its own 'corrections' to each pasted value, including removal of leading and trailing zeros.

The best solution is to use SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).  You can set the field formatting in SSRS, and then (if you choose) automate the export of your data to Excel by calling the report server by URL with `&rs:Format=excel`. (There is learning curve for SSRS but if you plan to continue doing things like this, it will be worth it.)

**Other options**

The easiest manual option is to 1) export the data to .csv format, 2) Open Excel and use the Text Import Wizard, and during Step 3 make sure to click the data column and then choose 'Text' as the data format. (You could automate this somewhat with an Excel VBA macro.)

The most complicated method involves programming using Excel VBA and ADO to automate the connection and querying of the data from your database view, and then rendering that data to a spreadsheet, using VBA to set the formatting to 'Text.'

Comment: Oh wow, I had a feeling it was something simple that would make it work.

Comment: I had been just opening the file, but the text import wizard did it. Setting the field to text first was the key. I was SURE that I remembered a way of making it a lot easier. Thanks a bunch for this.